# MYSQL using alias in the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I've read that you cannot use an ALIAS in a WHERE clause, but I still haven't a good alternative solution to achieve what I'm trying to do below. What can I do with my DISTANCE calculation so that it's available in the WHERE clause?

```
SELECT n.nid AS nid, location.name AS location_name, (6371.0 * ACOS(SIN((location.latitude * RADIANS(1))) * SIN((28.755925 * RADIANS(1))) + COS((location.latitude * RADIANS(1))) * COS((28.755925 * RADIANS(1))) * COS((location.longitude * RADIANS(1)) - (-81.346395 * RADIANS(1))))) AS distance
            FROM 
            node n
            LEFT JOIN location_instance ON n.vid = location_instance.vid
            LEFT JOIN location ON location_instance.lid = location.lid
            WHERE (( (n.status = '1') AND (n.type IN  ('locations')) AND (distance <= 100) ))
            ORDER BY distance
            LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You have to repeat it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL extends the use of the `HAVING` clause, which can be used for this purpose.  If the query is not an aggregation query, then `HAVING` still does filtering -- but it allows aliases.

So, you can write:

```
SELECT n.nid AS nid, l.name AS l, (6371.0 * ACOS(SIN((l.latitude * RADIANS(1))) * SIN((28.755925 * RADIANS(1))) + COS((l.latitude * RADIANS(1))) * COS((28.755925 * RADIANS(1))) * COS((l.longitude * RADIANS(1)) - (-81.346395 * RADIANS(1))))) AS distance
FROM node n LEFT JOIn
     location_instance li
     ON n.vid = li.vid LEFT JOIN
     location l
     ON li.lid = l.lid
WHERE n.status = 1 AND n.type IN ('locations') 
HAVING distance <= 100
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10;
```

Notes:

- If `status` is a number, which seems likely, then you should compare to a number, not a string.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Although `status` and `type` could go in the `HAVING` clause, I suspect that they are better in the `WHERE` (I suspect that `HAVING` could affect optimization choices).
- You could use a subquery, but that would store all the data in the table.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Didn't think HAVING would work with this computation.

Comment: @mrtonyb - HAVING is not WHERE. WHERE reduce the rows and HAVING filter the resultset. so where is much faster and can use index

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the optimization choices. I initially thought of mentioning HAVING but such concerns put me off; now that I have had more time to consider, with a complex condition calculation such as that, I doubt any optimizations would be possible in the WHERE clause... it might even be faster if MySQL doesn't concern itself with it so early.